# Grails loosing time information of a Date when parsing JSON

Tags: java, date, grails

My grails API is getting the time string but is loosing the seconds info.

I receive "16/02/2023 17:52:31" and results in a Date object with "16/02/2023 17:52:00"

```
class SampleObject {
    static hasOne = [timeObject: TimeObject]
}

class TimeObject { 
    Date begin
    Date end
    
    static belongsTo = [sampleObject: SampleObject]
    
    static constraints = {
        begin nullable: true
        end nullable: true
        sampleObject nullable: false, unique: true
    }
}

def controllerMethod() {

    def bodyJSON = request.reader.text

    def sampleObject = new SampleObject (JSON.parse(bodyJSON))
    
    println sampleObject
}
```

In this sample above I send:

```
{
    sampleObject: { 
        "begin": "16/02/2023 17:52:31",
        "end": "16/02/2023 17:53:12"
    }
}
```

Result:

> begin= {Date@16875} "Thu Feb 16 17:52:00 BRT 2023"
>
> end= {Date@16876} "Thu Feb 16 17:53:00 BRT 2023"

In my application.groovy I have:

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = ['dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"]
```

PS: I'm using grails 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the "grails.databinding.dateFormats" order.

I solve changing to this:

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = ['dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"]
```